# Fourier transform of almost-periodic lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, diffraction, crystals

For a perfectly periodic lattice of atoms, the density can be written as a Fourier series like any other periodic function. This Fourier representation is very useful, because it can be connected to peaks you can measure with diffraction.

Mathematically this is written as:
$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=\sum_j \rho(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_j)=\sum_{\mathbf{G}} \rho_{\mathbf{G}} e^{i \mathbf{G}\cdot  \mathbf{r}}$$

Where $\mathbf{G}$ are the reciprocal lattice vectors. In ordinary diffraction you measure diffraction peaks at the reciprocal lattice vectors with intensity $\vert  \rho_{\mathbf{G}} \vert^2$. Coherent diffraction can further get the phase of these coefficients.

Now let's assume that the crystal has strain fields, causing atoms to deviate from their perfect crystal position by $\delta \mathbf{r}_j$. Now we cannot write the charge density as a simple Fourier series because it is no longer periodic.

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=\sum_j \rho(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_j - \delta \mathbf{r}_j ) \neq\sum_{\mathbf{G}} \rho_{\mathbf{G}} e^{i \mathbf{G}\cdot  \mathbf{r}}$$

My question is: **is there a useful Fourier-*like* series of the density when strain is introduced?**. At first thought I would assume $\delta r_j \ll r_j$ and do a Taylor series in $\delta r_j/r_j$ but in the case of a dislocation (very common type of strain) they become the same order of magnitude so that isn't quite right.

As an example, in the literature on strain field imaging with [electron microscopy](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature01638), a Fourier series-like form is suggested.

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=\sum_{\mathbf{G}} \rho_{\mathbf{G}}(\mathbf{r}) e^{i \mathbf{G}\cdot  \mathbf{r}}$$

Where in the paper above $\rho_{\mathbf{G}}(\mathbf{r})\equiv A_{\mathbf{G}}(\mathbf{r}) e^{i \mathbf{G}\cdot  \delta\mathbf{r}}$ treating $\mathbf{r}$ and $\delta \mathbf{r}$ as continuous variables.
This form for $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ looks conceptually appealing, but as far as I can tell it is ad-hoc, and non-rigorous in general. Any insights here?

Comment: Related: [Debye--Waller factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye%E2%80%93Waller_factor).

Comment: @knzhou thank you. The Debye Waller effect is a great example of dealing with the averaged behavior of a disordered lattice. Maybe there is a similar way to get a particular instance of disorder to extract its strain field. I'll have to think about this some more

Comment: You could add a modulation whose period is incommensurate with the lattice spacing. That would displace the minimum location by a "random" amount for each lattice site...

Comment: Does the symbol $\rho$ in equation $\rho(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_j \rho(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_j)$ denote the same thing on the right- and on the left-hand side? I think $\rho$ on the left is a total (charge/atomic/wave function/whatever) density, while $\rho$ on the right is a contribution from a single atom.